# MainActivity NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: android, android-studio, android-activity, android-manifest

I seem to be having a similar problem to a myriad of the community; however, I don't seem to have the same symptoms (or at the very least, my Google-fu is not allowing me to find it).

Long story short: The app is giving me `java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity`.

From what I understand this can only be caused by improper order of loading libraries or by missing the file in the AndroidManifest.xml.

Here is my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="net.alexanderlyons.livingpokedex">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

[Here is a link to my repository for those wanting to build it themselves.](https://github.com/alyons/Living-Pokedex) If anyone can give me insight as to what might be wrong.

Note: This may be due to my .gitignore, as the last time I built, it was on my main tower. I am only running into this issue on a remote machine.

TL:DR - My MainActivity is not loading, it exists in the AndriodManifest.xml, and I am only using gradles to load files, not local jars.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem can be caused by different things, but the most common of it is you having too many libraries loaded, with too many methods.

You should enable multidex in your app, here's the guide:

[multidex](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/tools/building/multidex.html)

A quick tutorial:

Add "multiDexEnabled true" to your gradle config (under  target sdk version, for example).

Add this to your dependencies:

```
dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}
```

And make sure you application extends this:

```
<application
        ...
        android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication">
        ...
    </application>
```

Either via code or via manifest.

*Edit:*

Test the project with the build tools 22, sd version 22 and target 22. Also, use the support libraries 22.+

Comment: This did not fix my issue. I currently only using what I believe to be a few libraries. [This is my app build.gradle](https://github.com/alyons/Living-Pokedex/blob/master/Andriod/LivingPokedex/app/build.gradle); does it seem as though I am loading too many libraries?

Comment: You should try this workaround a friend of mine used to find the problem : 
Test the project with the build tools 22, sd version 22 and target 22. Also, use the support libraries 22.+